# npm update -g on Windows fails

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm tearing my hair out here. When I run `npm update -g` from a non-elevated command prompt I get this:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-05T20_50_19_641Z-debug.log
```

Why the hell is it trying to create a .staging directory under `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\`?? It should be creating it under `C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`. That's where my modules are installed. I shouldn't need to run the command as administrator.

EDIT: Fine, I ran the command as administrator, even though it makes no damn sense, and guess what? It still refuses to do it!

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-05T21_23_18_719Z-debug.log
```

Looks like it's trying to update npm itself. I delete npm.cmd and...

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Oh right! How stupid of me! Well now I have no npm command and have to reinstall Node.js.

UPDATE: Did a repair install of NodeJS, then went back to administrator command prompt and...

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-05T21_56_28_029Z-debug.log
```

What the actual...?! Does no one have an answer to this?! Am I supposed to just wipe my Node installation completely??

Comment: run in a cmd as administrador

Answer (score 1):

EPERM: operation not permitted => your user cannot create a folder

solution:

1- open a cmd as administrator (right click over option cmd)

Comment: Why should I have to run it as administrator when I'm updating packages that belong to me? It makes no sense.

Comment: -g == global => all users

Comment: Since when? If that were true, then why does -g, under normal circumstances, cause it to install to C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm?